# Grouping a seq by different sizes - Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following data:

```
(def letters [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g ])
(def group-sizes [2 3 2])
```

What would be an idiomatic way to group letters by size, such that I get:

```
[[:a :b] [:c :d :e] [:f :g]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(->> group-sizes
     (reductions + 0)
     (partition 2 1)
     (map (partial apply subvec letters)))
```

This algorithm requires the input coll `letters` to be a vector and to have at least the required amount of `(apply + group-sizes)` elements. It returns a lazy seq (or a vector if you use `mapv`) of vectors that share structure with the input vector.

Thanks to subvec they are created in O(1), constant time so the overall time complexity should be O(N) where N is `(count group-sizes)`, compared to Diegos algorithm where N would be the drastically higher `(count letters)`.

Answer (score 4):

After I started writing my answer, I noticed, that [*Leon Grapenthin*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25465812/1202461) is almost identical to mine.

Here is my version of it:

```
(let [end   (reductions + group-sizes)
      start (cons 0 end)]
  (map (partial subvec letters) start end))
```

The only difference from [*Leon Grapenthin*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25465812/1202461) is that I'm using `let` and `cons` instead of `partition` and `apply`.

Note, that both solutions consume `group-sizes` lazily, thus producing a lazy sequence as an output.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the best way (e.g. you may want to check that the sum of the group sizes is the same as the size of letters to avoid an NPE) but it was my first thought:

```
(defn sp [[f & r] l]
  (when (seq l)
    (cons (take f l)
          (sp r (drop f l)))))
```

You could also do it with an accumulator and `recur` if you have a long list and don't want to blow up the stack.

Comment: This looks good to me. You could make it lazy (and avoid blowing up the stack with long sequences) by simply wrapping the body of the function in lazy-seq.